# Super Street Fighter 4 for PC runs very slowly

Tags: pc, super-street-fighter-iv

I recently installed SSFIV on my new PC. It runs extremely slowly. What can I do to fix this? I don't believe that its a hardware problem as my PC is brand new and can play more resource-intensive games than this.

I am playing offline on a dual-core, 3.2 GHz, 32-bit PC. I have turned off v-sync and I'm playing at maximum screen resolution.

Comment: you'll need to provide more information.  Is this slow vs the computer or are you doing online play?  Have you tried turning off vsync?

Comment: dual core 32 bit?  That doesn't sound like a brand new computer imo.  What graphics cards do you have.

Comment: @z-: Intel GMA 4500

Comment: then i'd say that's your issue right there.  SSF4 is suprisingly graphically demanding.  And because the game is completely tied to framerates, if you can't push the framerate, the entire game slows down.

Comment: @z-: "Framerates": I've tried the game on all settings. It works normally when I used fixed framerate. Thanks for the clue

Comment: cool, suprising that you can get the game going on a gma4500, but its good you can actually play the game now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running a game on a computer that does not meet the minimum system requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video card does not meet the [minimum system requirements](http://thesystemrequirement.blogspot.com/2011/07/super-street-fighter-iv-arcade-edition.html) for the game.

Because everything in SSF4 is tied to frames and framerate, if you can't push the framerate, then the entire game slows down to match.

Looking at the [benchmarks for your videocard](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-4500MHD-GMA-X4500MHD.9883.0.html) it can't even handle most games at low settings.  This isn't suprising since its an integrated card and the GMA4500 is one of the low end ones in that area.